# Python: for-iteration through a utf-8 string -> what's the data type/encoding of the iterators?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a utf-8 encoded strings(mainly Chinese + some english), and want to run a letter count on them. (similar to English word count).

So I used

```
for letter in text:    # text is a utf-8 encoded str
```

but I'm not sure what I'm getting as a 'letter'. 'text' print in screen fine and write to csv fine. But the 'letter' in 'for letter in text' looks all crashed both on screen and in csv file. I think it's definitely some problem related with encoding, but adding `.encode('utf-8')` here and there doesn't solve the problem and returns error like

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What I mean is the code below doesn't return error but the letters look all crashed, and it returns the above error message when I add .encode('utf-8') to 
print `letter.encode('utf-8')` or `wcwriter.writerows([[k.encode('utf-8'), v]])`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...

with open(fname+'.csv', 'wb') as twfile:
    twwriter = csv.writer(twfile)
    twwriter.writerows([[u'Date/Time', u'Text', u'ID', u'Location', u'City', u'Province']])

    for statuses in jres.get('statuses'): # jres is a json format response returned from a API call request
        text = statuses.get('text').encode('utf-8')

        if keyword in text:
            td = statuses.get('created_at').encode('utf-8')
            name = statuses.get('user').get('screen_name').encode('utf-8')
            loc = statuses.get('user').get('location').encode('utf-8')
            city = statuses.get('user').get('city').encode('utf-8')
            province = statuses.get('user').get('province').encode('utf-8')

            twwriter.writerows([[td, text, name, loc, city, province]])
            keycount += 1

# this is the problematic part. I'm not sure exactly what data type or encoding I'm getting for 'letter' below 

            for letter in text:
                if letter not in dismiss:
                    print letter   # this will print a lot of crushed letters
                    if letter not in wordcount:
                        wordcount[letter] = 1
                    else:
                        wordcount[letter] += 1

with open(wcname+'.csv', 'wb') as wcfile:
    wcwriter = csv.writer(wcfile)
    wcwriter.writerows([[u'Letter', u'Number']])

    for k, v in wordcount.items():
        wcwriter.writerows([[k, v]])
```

Comment: What Python version is in use? In 2.x, `str` is a list of bytes and `unicode` is a list of characters, whereas in 3.x `str` is a list of characters and `bytes` is a list of bytes.

Comment: @TomHunt: this is clearly Python 2; note the `print` statement. Other clues: using `'rb'` for the CSV files as advised by the `csv` module, and the `u'..'` string literals for Unicode data.

Comment: I think I'm working on Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 encoded bytes may print fine to the screen or write fine to a file, but that's only because both your screen (terminal or console) and whatever reading the file also understand UTF-8.

UTF-8 encoding uses *one or more bytes* per codepoint. Iteration doesn't step through the data codepoint by codepoint but byte by byte. So the character `'å'` is encoded to UTF8 as two bytes, C3 and A5. Trying to handle those two bytes as letters is going to create problems:

```
>>> 'å'
'\xc3\xa5'
>>> for byte in 'å':
...     print repr(byte)
... 
'\xc3'
'\xa5'
```

You should **decode** to `unicode` values so that Python knows about the codepoints encoded by the bytes instead, or where you already have Unicode, *not* encode:

```
>>> for codepoint in 'å'.decode('utf8'):
...     print repr(codepoint), codepoint
... 
u'\xe5' å
```

Your exception is caused when you try to encode *already encoded bytes*. Python tries to be helpful by first decoding the bytes to Unicode so that it can comply and encode back to bytes, but it can only do so with the default ASCII encoding. That is why you get a `UnicodeDecodeError` (note the `Decode` in there) when trying to use `encode()`:

```
>>> 'å'.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Generally speaking, you want to treat text as Unicode as much as possible. Implement a Unicode *sandwich*, decode from bytes to Unicode as early as possible, and only encode when you are writing out your data back to a file, as late as possible. The JSON data you are processing is already Unicode, so you only need to encode to UTF8 when producing your CSV rows, *but not earlier*.

In this case that means you should **not** encode `text`:

```
for statuses in jres.get('statuses'): # jres is a json format response returned from a API call request
    text = statuses['text']
```

and instead only encode it when you are passing it to the CSV writer:

```
twwriter.writerows([[td, text.encode('utf8'), name, loc, city, province]])
```

You probably want to do some studying on the difference between Unicode and encodings, and how that relates to Python:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Even with decoded utf-8, Python seems to separate emojis, etc into multiple codepoints. I used the following function to solve this issue:

```
# ustr must be "decoded" unicode string, e.g. u""
def each_utf8_char(ustr, pointer=0):
  ustr = ustr.encode('utf-8')
  slen = len(ustr)
  char = ustr[pointer] if slen > pointer else False
  while char:
    charVal = ord(char)
    if charVal < 128:
      bytes = 1
    elif charVal < 224:
      bytes = 2
    elif charVal < 240:
      bytes = 3
    elif charVal < 248:
      bytes = 4
    elif charVal == 252:
      bytes = 5
    else:
      bytes = 6
    yield ustr[pointer:pointer+bytes].decode('utf-8')
    pointer += bytes
    char = ustr[pointer] if slen > pointer else False
```

It's a generator, so you use it like this:

```
my_ustr = u' Cheers!'
for char in each_utf8_char(my_ustr):
  print char
```